# Oops! Unable to access Azure's API

Tags: docker, azure

I'm trying to connect my Docker and Azure accounts and am following the Docker instructions.

to start, the instructions (found [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/link-azure/)) require me to log into Azure using the "old" portal (ancient). I cannot seem to do that because the old portal is apparently not available to all types of accounts and is not available to me.

but no matter, I figured out how to upload the certificate I downloaded from Docker to Azure. next I entered the Subscription ID from Azure into Docker, but I get the error: "Oops! Unable to access Azure's API. The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription"

the subscription ID I entered is for a virtual machine (classic) which is running Ubuntu.

I've posted to the [Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/azure-certificate-installation/7350) but so far no replies so I'm hoping someone here has done a docker deployment to Azure.

thanks in advance.